# How to calculate the number of days a record appeared in a specific month?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to calculate the number of days a record appears in a specific month. I have a "Start_Date" column, "End_Date" column, and my new column is "Days_In_March".

The date format; 2019-03-01

I am trying to populate the "Days_In_March" column with the number of days that a record appeared in this month.

So if it had a start date of 2019-02-25 and end date of 2019-03-10; it would put "10" in the "Days_In_March" column.

I have had a look at postgres documentation and through stackoverflow, however I cannot find anything which addresses this problem.

```
UPDATE table1
SET "Days_In_March" = 

WHERE "Start_Date" AND "End_Date" BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31';
```

I am obviously missing gaps in my code, but this is what I arrived at following a logical process. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Postgres' [date range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) for that:

```
update the_table
  set days_in_march = upper(overlap) - lower(overlap)
from (
  select id, 
         daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') * daterange(date '2019-03-01', date '2019-04-01', '[)') as overlap
  from the_table
  where daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') && daterange(date '2019-03-01', date '2019-04-01', '[)')
) x
where x.id = the_table.id;
```

The expression `daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') * daterange(date '2019-03-01', date '2019-04-01', '[)')` calculates the intersection between the range "march" and the range defined by start_date and end_date returning the start and end dates of that intersection. The difference between those two dates is the number of days in march.

If you want to see what exactly those operators do, run the inner sub-query on its own.

The `where` clause in the inner select only selects rows that actually define a period that falls at least partially into march. If you want to set `days_in_march` for those rows to `null` just remove the where clause from the inner select.

This assumes that the primary key column of the table is named `id`

Online example: https://rextester.com/HHOZ16614

---

If you need to calculate this often, you can create a function for this:

```
create or replace function days_overlap(p_start date, p_end date, p_ref_start, p_ref_end date)
  returns integer
as
$$
  select upper(overlap) - lower(overlap) 
  from (select p_to_test * p_reference as overlap) x;
$$ 
language sql
immutable;
```

Then the update becomes as simple as:

```
update the_table
  set days_in_march = days_overlap(daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]'), 
                                   daterange(date '2019-03-01', date '2019-04-01', '[)') )
where ...;
```

---

Given how easy it is to calculate this number, I would probably get rid of that column completely and provide that through a view.

Comment: Works! Thanks again horse_with_no_name!

Answer (score 0):

We can try calendar table approach here, where we left join your current table to the calendar table, and then aggregate to turn out the number of days in March:

```
WITH march_days AS (
    SELECT date::date 
    FROM generate_series('2019-03-01'::date, '2019-03-31'::date, '1 day'::interval) date
)

SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(md.date) AS days_in_march
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN march_days md
    ON md.date BETWEEN t1.start_date AND t1.end_date
GROUP BY
    id;
```

Note that I assume that there exists some sort of unique identifier/column in your `table1` table which can be used to exclusively identify every row.  This is needed in order for the aggregation step to be possible.